# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in python (problem)

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code

```
pageNameOrId = 'Ch3Thailand'
source_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/pg/%s/posts/' % pageNameOrId
content = html.unescape(requests.get(source_url).text)
postInfos = getPostInfosFromContent(content)
posts = getPostsFromContent(content, postInfos)
urlResult = re.search(r'\/pages_reaction_units.*?unit_count=8', content).group()
print(len(posts), posts[-1])
```

and get errors like this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-69969f51fdc6> in <module>()
----> 6 urlResult = re.search(r'\/pages_reaction_units.*?unit_count=8', content).group()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Your regex didn't match anything so re.search returned None

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
re.search(r'\/pages_reaction_units.*?unit_count=8', content)
```

Simply equals to `None`. Perhaps the regex didn't match anything, so it returned `None`.